# Can you manipulate someone's memories?

Tags: death-note

So. I now know that you can manipulate someone's thoughts. For example: Naomi Misora.

But what I'm asking myself is, whether or not you can manipulate someone's memories. For example, Bob and John are best friends, right? So what if I write this:

> Bob Shneizel forgets who his best friend is, and then dies of diabetes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule was that the Death Note user can make people do anything s/he wants them to, as long as it is possible. For example, let's say Kira wrote

> September 7, 2015 8:30 A.M. Mr. A dies of a heart attack in Kyuushu. Mr. A starts running from Tokyo at 6 A.M. on the same day, before dying of said cause in Kyuushu.

Since this is impossible, it won't happen as written. He will still die of a heart attack, but not in Kyuushu. Now, would it be possible for someone to forget his best friend? Yes, it would. Amnesia. If you write it like that, then Bob will experience amnesia before dying from diabetes.